# &amp; Causes String to Split When Sent to Server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, html-entities, ngresource

I am sending a string to the server using `ng-resource`. If I add `&amp;` into the string at any point, the characters after `&amp;` are not sent to the server.

For example if I send the string to the server:

```
"This part of the string is shown &amp; this part of the string is NOT shown"
```

everything after `&amp;` is never shown. It's as if it's been chopped before being sent to the server.

Here is a working code sample.

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngResource'])

.service('TestService', testService)

.controller('Controller', theController);

function testService() {
  this.$get = get;

  get.$inject = ['$resource'];

  function get( $resource ) {
    var baseUrl = window.location['origin'];

    var theResource = $resource(
      baseUrl + '/test_url',
      {},
      {
        testMe: {method: 'GET', url: '/test_url'}
       }
    )

    return theResource;
  }
}

theController.$inject = ["TestService"];

function theController(TestService) {
  activate();

  function activate() {
    var stringToSend = "this part of the string is shown &amp; this part of the string will NOT be shown";

    // The server will only see the text "this part of the string is shown &amp;"
    TestService.testMe({stringParam: stringToSend}, function(resp) {});
  }
}
```

What's wrong and how do I fix this?

PS: When I mean `not shown`, I mean it's as if that part of the string was never sent.

Comment: Something isn't URL Encoding the string before sticking it in the URL. I can't find where `stringParam` is read in that code though.

Comment: It is because you send it as a part of the query string and the & works as a part of the query string to split the parameters. Instead try to send it as a post request. It should wrap the parameters in the request body and then you will receive all of it.

Comment: Whoever posted the `encodeURI` answer was correct. Unfortunately, they deleted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do `encode` the string before send it to server using `encodeURI` method. I think decoding of parameter value will happen automatically.

**Code**

```
TestService.testMe({
  stringParam: encodeURI(stringToSend)
}, function(resp) {});
```

Comment: @jason328 glad to hear that. Thanks :-)